# Derivative of the multiple variable function

Tags: derivatives

What is the derivative of f at P (1,1) in the direction of u?

$$f(x,y) = x\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$$

$$\vec{u} = 2\vec{i} - \vec{j} $$

Comment: I tried to get the partial derivative of x and y, and calculated fx(1,1)・2 + fy(1,1)・(-1).  But the answer was wrong.

Comment: $f_x (x,y) = \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}-\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ and $f_y (x,y) = \frac{x^2}{y^2+x^2} $ also notice that you need to convert $\vec{u}$ to a unit vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\nabla f=(\arctan\dfrac{y}{x}-\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2},\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2})$$
$$\nabla f(p)=(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2})$$
$$\nabla f(p).\vec{\bf e}_u=(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}).(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{5}})=\color{blue}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\dfrac{\pi-3}{2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$x=1+2t,y=1-t$$ and compute the derivative at $t=0$,

$$\left((1+2t)\arctan\frac{1-t}{1+2t}\right)'=2\arctan\frac{1-t}{1+2t}+(1+2t)\frac{\dfrac{-(1+2t)-2(1-t)}{(1+2t)^2}}{1+\left(\dfrac{1-t}{1+2t}\right)^2}.$$

At $t=0$, this gives

$$\frac\pi2-\frac32.$$

Anyway, as the vector $\vec u$ isn't normalized, the computed derivative is too large by a factor $\sqrt5$, hence

$$\frac{\pi-3}{2\sqrt5}.$$